# Emergency mode after resizing logical volumes on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I run the latest version of ubuntu server on a personal computer at home that I use as a server.
I have two logical volumes on it. `vg0` and `vg1`. Recently, I noticed that my partition `/dev/vg0/lv-var` mounted at `/var` was too small. I backed up everything in `/var` and `/home` and proceeded to reduce the `/dev/vg0/lv-home` partition and increase the `/dev/vg0/lv-var` partition.
The commands I used looked like this:

```
umount /home
lvreduce --size 325G /dev/vg0/lv-home
lvextend -L +100.22G /dev/vg0/lv-var
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/vg0-lv--var
```

Everthing seemed to have worked. Notice that I did not `umount /var` though as it was used by many essential processes.

After a reboot, the system now boots into `emergency mode` I can't even use a keyboard to troubleshoot because it has trouble handling usb connections and I get an error similar to `unable to enumerate USB device`

I feel that there might be an issue with the fact that I did not remount `/home` before rebooting.

Trying to mount home while in safe mode I get:

`mount: /home: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vg0-lv--home.`

When the system boots up I can see:

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /home. (100.0% complete)
```

I tried `xfs_repair` but I can't even mount the volume anywhere because I get `can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vg0-lv--home`

I am considering deleting the logical volume, creating a new one and mounting it to home. I have backups of my data, but how can I do this and allow the system to know to mount the newly created `/home` on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I backed up everything in `/var` and `/home`

That's great! You'll need that backup of `/home` now.

You used `lvreduce` without `--resizefs` and without first shrinking the filesystem inside it. As a result, you have cut off part of your `/home` filesystem, and it's now damaged and causing you to drop into emergency mode.

If your `/home` is an XFS filesystem, it is currently impossible to shrink it non-destructively anyway. Making a backup, then shrinking the partition/logical volume, then re-`mkfs`ing the shrunk partition/LV and restoring the backup is for now the only available (production-quality) way to shrink an XFS filesystem.

So, temporarily comment out the `/home` entry in your `/etc/fstab` in emergency mode to let the system come up more or less normally, boot to get out of emergency mode, then re-`mkfs` the `/dev/vg0/lv-home`, uncomment the `/etc/fstab` entry for `/home`, mount it, and restore the contents of your `/home` from backup.

You should think about it in layers:

- the physical disk is fine
- the partition used as the LVM physical volume is fine
- the LVM logical volume layer was properly shrunk, so it is also fine
- the filesystem within the logical volume was not shrunk, so it's had its tail end cut off.

If the filesystem type on `/home` was XFS, you'll just need to run `sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/vg0/lv-home` and the filesystem will be good to mount again (although empty). After that, it'll be just a matter of restoring the contents from backup.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that tonight :) I'm wondering, for the future, what would have been the good way to reduce my home volume? Lastly, would you be willing to give me an example to delete the corrupted volume, freeing the space, creating a new one and re-adding and to fstab?

Comment: Thanks again, it worked wonders. I am still asking myself, is there a possibility that the /var volume that was extended and grown could cause trouble or have I done it properly?

Comment: You did the `/var` extension correctly. I would expect no trouble at all from that.